# how to find all possiblie outcomes for a 6 x 6 grid?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This is more of a programming problem that I have but I need to know all the possible outcomes of a combination of 6 different Boolean variables, hence the 6x6 grid. I don't know if that's the correct way to look a the problem but here we go. I need to find this in order to write the if statements that handle the outcomes:

var1 = true and var2 = true and var3 = true and var4 = true and var5 = true and var6 = true

And so on until I have an IF statement for every possible outcome.

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not be using a $6\times6$ grid. Since each variable can take on the value of True or False, you have $2^6=64$ possible truth-value combinations to consider, not $36$

Indeed, why are you thinking of a $6 \times 6$ grid?  Because you have for each variable a column that represents the variable being true, and a row where it is false?  But then what would be in grid-cell $(1,1)$?  The result of the function where variable $1$ is both true and false?  And what would be the values of the other variables? Clearly that's not what you want. Whatever grid you come up with, each cell needs to represent a combination of truth-values for *all* variables. Look at [Karnaugh Maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) to see how to do this for multiple variables.

Here is an example K-Map for $6$ variables:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! I am not a programmer and not great at math. I broke my brain today trying to solve this. Now I need to start coding possibilities... Thank you again!

Comment: @WestWindsDemon You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

No, $6\times 6$ is not enough to represent the $2^6$ cases. Instead, you could let your variables form a string whose values will then be the $2^6$ strings $000000,000001,...,111111$. These correspond to the binary representations of the numbers $0,1,...,2^6-1$, so you could just generate those numbers in a loop and work with their binary representations.

Comment: Interesting, I'll look into this route.

Comment: This simplified the way I thought about my code, considerably. Now I  just need to code a select case with 63 cases... Wish me luck!